# Looker Studio custom visualization using Google Charts results in empty page

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, looker-studio, data-studio-custom-visuals

I realized a custom visualization for Looker Studio using the approach explained in this [Codelab](https://developers.google.com/looker-studio/visualization/get-started) as well as this [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7axX1R_ttOI) exploiting the d3 library. I am basically happy with the result, but it turns out the visualization does not blend in well with Looker Studio standard components.

At this point I realized I would be able to use Google's own library Google Charts. My hope is that the resulting graph will look more native to the Looker Studio environment. However, I have trouble implementing Google Charts code. The following example of a very fundamental line graph is provided by Google, so I assume it must be working:

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2004',  1000,      400],
          ['2005',  1170,      460],
          ['2006',  660,       1120],
          ['2007',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          curveType: 'function',
          legend: { position: 'bottom' }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is how I tried to do the same thing for the custom visualization:

```
const dscc = require('@google/dscc');
const viz = require('@google/dscc-scripts/viz/initialViz.js');
const local = require('./localMessage.js');

// write viz code here
const drawViz = (data) => {
  // Create the script tag
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js";
  script.type = "text/javascript";

  // Append the script tag to the head of the document
  document.head.appendChild(script);

  // Create the div tag
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = "curve_chart";
  div.style.width = "900px";
  div.style.height = "500px";

  // Append the div tag to the body of the document
  document.body.appendChild(div);

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
};

drawViz(local.message);
```

using `npm run start` to inspect the result on the localhost, does not produce any errors, but the output is simply entirely empty. HTML and JavaScript are not exactly my strengths, so I am pretty lost even on where to look for the problem and a solution. I feel like it is only a minor oversight and I am hoping you can help me.

Thanks in advance!

**What I tried**

- including google-charts via `const google = require('google-charts');` after installing it with npm. However, my new friend chat gpt told me that wouldn't be necessary
- The following lines in the script above were already attempts to add necessary infrastructure to the enclosing HTML-document. It did not help, though

```
  // Create the script tag
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js";
  script.type = "text/javascript";

  // Append the script tag to the head of the document
  document.head.appendChild(script);

  // Create the div tag
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = "curve_chart";
  div.style.width = "900px";
  div.style.height = "500px";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may need to wait for the google script to load before trying to use it.

see `script.onload` and `loadGoogle`

```
const dscc = require('@google/dscc');
const viz = require('@google/dscc-scripts/viz/initialViz.js');
const local = require('./localMessage.js');

// write viz code here
const drawViz = (data) => {
  // Create the script tag
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js";
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.onload = loadGoogle;
  
  // Append the script tag to the head of the document
  document.head.appendChild(script);

  // Create the div tag
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.id = "curve_chart";
  div.style.width = "900px";
  div.style.height = "500px";

  // Append the div tag to the body of the document
  document.body.appendChild(div);
  
  function loadGoogle() {
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  }
  
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance',
      curveType: 'function',
      legend: { position: 'bottom' }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
};

drawViz(local.message);
```